# JS: Why does break in a loop interfere with .splice?

Tags: javascript, loops, break

### Link to all the code and how it works:

[Where it works](http://jsbin.com/kuweze/6/)

Just make the SUM() or SUBTRACT() functions anywhere. Then you can click in any boxes and it will highlight it, if you click it again in the console.log the numbers are supposed to dissapear. But they add on and on... Done doesn't work yet, but cancel does. Good luck

---

Basically, the code is supposed to go through numbers that it recieves and when its found, it deletes the number that is inside a variable that stores other numbers. This occurs inside a table, so any number is added randomly. If something is clicked by accident, then this "*handy*" little function is supposed to remove the info from the variable **numbers**.

When I take away the break inside the loop, it works better, which is unexpected. **Without** the break it will delete numbers, but always leave **one** number inside the numbers variable. If there are multiple instances of one number, it removes all except, *on certain occasions*, one of them. **But with** the break, it doesn't even remove one number at all.

I have narrowed it down to the below code, but I will also add the entire function, and of course describe each variable that isn't first made inside that function. The reason why I'm not giving **ALL THE CODE** is because its over *200* lines and I'm sure you'd rather just read some of that portion.

### Below is the faulty code

```
    var splitN = numbers.split(",");
                        for (var j = 0; j < splitN.length - 1; j++) {
                            if (splitN[j] === this.innerHTML) {
                                var location = splitN.indexOf(splitN[j]);
                                splitN.splice(location, 1);
                                numbers = splitN.toString();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
```

### Below is the whole function with descriptions of everything

```
    function create_onclick() {
        table = Gid("main_sheet"); //Gid is a function that used document.getElementById, and main_sheet is the table
        cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
        for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
            cells[i].onclick = function() {
                table = Gid("main_sheet");
                cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');
                if (sum || subtract || equation) { //all 3 variables are not necassirly needed, as it only determines whether to activate the following code
                    numbers += (this.innerHTML + ","); //Starts setting up the numbers variable, it has an extra comma at the end always
                    cells_used += (i + ",");
                    Gid("main_sheet").style.cursor = "cell";
                    if (this.style.backgroundColor === "blue") { //If the cell is blue, then it will begin to remove some data when it's clicked
                        this.style.backgroundColor = "#EEEEEE"; //Sets it back to gray-ish color
                        var splitN = numbers.split(","); //Gets ready for the loop below
                        for (var j = 0; j < splitN.length - 1; j++) {
                            if (splitN[j] === this.innerHTML) {
                                var location = splitN.indexOf(splitN[j]); //Determines location of the number
                                splitN.splice(location, 1);
                                numbers = splitN.toString(); //Converts it back to a string and sets numbers value to the new value
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                            this.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
                    } else {
                        this.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; //Sets it to blue if it wasn't blue
                        this.setAttribute("contentEditable", false);
                    }

                    console.log(numbers); //Used for debugging purposes
                } else {
                Gid("main_sheet").style.cursor = "text";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `j < splitN.length - 1` or `j < splitN.length` ?

Comment: I think you meant to have `j < splitN.length`, as abhitalks previously stated.

Comment: Is it really your intention to throw away the content of `numbers` on this line: `numbers = splitN.toString();` ? The comment kinda implies that but you never know... Just making sure.

Comment: Yes it was @RobertRossmann , I don't know if you read the top few paragraphs, but I thought I explained that I was trying to delete some things. And Abhitalks, I did that because there was always an extra part in the array, but I can check to see if you are correct.

Comment: @abhitalks that does not fix the problem. I simply used that because of the extra part at the end

Comment: @CoderJS: You code seemingly works fine in a sandbox. Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ah7da26o/ (And why have you complicated it with location variable? Why not just use the "j"?)

Comment: Hmmm... may be notepad++ that's messing it up. And haha I don't know why I didn't use j. I didn't quite think of that, if that works.

Comment: Doesn't work. I will give a link up top to where all the code is and how its supposed to work. @abhitalks

Comment: @CoderJS: I have created a small demo based on your use-case. I think this is what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ah7da26o/1/

Comment: Not particulaly @abhitalks . Unless I misunderstand what your code is doing, it basically just deletes it and re-adds it. I want it permenetly deleted, unless the user adds it again (clicks it again). Also, I would like it to be just in javascript, I'm not a huge fan of jQuery :P

Comment: @CoderJS: Hmmm... Will give it another try tomorrow, it's very late in night here.

Comment: @CoderJS: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ah7da26o/2/

Comment: @CoderJS: And this one is plain vanilla Javascript as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ah7da26o/3/

Comment: Hmmm alright @abhitalks I will use some of that stuff that you used in the javascript part, thanks for giving your time to help me :D

Comment: I have noticed that the change event could be a problem because if you click on it again nothing happens, I may just improvise tho